# PHP - Filling in automatic table from previous database entry

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, insert

I am trying to create automatic table which is filled from DB. In DB I have columns: `color1, clor2 … color30`. Number of colors which wanna insert depends on the calculation. Result of calculation is `$j`. I display table like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $j; $i++) { 
    echo "<tr class='text-center'><td class='col-sm-2 info'>";
        . "<td>" .  $row['color']
...
    . "</tr>"
    . "</td></td>”;
}
```

`$row['color']` should depend on `$i`. It is not possible write `$row['color$i']`. How to achieve it?

Comment: yes it is possible, a simple concatenation would work. either `$row['color' . $i]` or `$row["color$i"]`

Answer (score 1):

You could either prepare your string before using it in your $row array like this `$color='color'.$i` then use `$row[$color]` or use this directly. `$row["color".$i]` or `$row["color{$i}"]` should work as well

Comment: Also `$row["color$i"]` -- because double-quotes allow "interpolation" but single-quotes do not.